# Elixir : how to display a structured data element?

Tags: csv, erlang, elixir

I'm trying to parse a CSV file. Actually I have this code :

```
alias NimbleCSV.RFC4180, as: CSV

defmodule Siren do
  def parseCSV do
    IO.puts("Let's parse CSV file!")

    stream = File.stream!("name.csv")
    original_line = CSV.parse_stream(stream)
    filter_line = Stream.filter(original_line, fn
      ["JeremyGuthrie" | _] -> true
      _ -> false
    end)
    map = Stream.map(filter_line,
    fn [name, team, position, height, weight, age] ->
      %{name: name, team: team, position: position,
      height: String.to_integer(height),
      weight: String.to_integer(weight),
      age: Float.parse(age) |> elem(0)
      }
    end)
  end
end
```

According to my view I build a stream who handle each line of my name.csv file. With NimbleCSV library I parse this line and avoid the header line. Then, I filter each line to keep only the one corresponding to JeremyGuthrie. And finally I stock the line element into a structured data map. But now how to print just the name of my filter line : here JeremyGuthrie.

**And I have an other question** : I'm having some problems to filter my stream according to a number like an age, height or weight.

Here I apply Aleksei's advice with another code :

```
NimbleCSV.define(MyParser, separator: ";", escape: "\"")

defmodule Siren do
  def parseCSV do
    IO.puts("Let's parse CSV file!")

    "ActeursEOF.csv"
    |> File.stream!()
    |> MyParser.parse_stream()
    |> Stream.filter(fn
      ["RAZEL BEC" | _] -> true
      ["" | _] -> false
      _ -> false
    end)
    |> Stream.map(fn [name, description, enr_competences] ->
      %{name: name, description: description, enr_competences: enr_competences}
    end)
    |> Enum.to_list()
    |> IO.inspect()
  end
end
```

My output:

```
Compiling 1 file (.ex)
Let's parse CSV file!
[%{description: "Génie Civil", enr_competences: "Oui", name: "RAZEL BEC"}]
```

But now to close this subject I would to access and stock just the description for instance. And I don't see how to do that... And finally display this data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Producing intermediate variables is redundant, in [elixir](/questions/tagged/elixir) we have [`Kernel.|>/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Kernel.html?#%7C%3E/2) aka pipe operator to pipe the functions’ output to the first argument of the next function.

```rb
"name.csv"
|> File.stream!()
|> CSV.parse_stream()
|> Stream.filter(fn
  ["JeremyGuthrie" | _] -> true
  _ -> false
end)
|> Stream.map(fn
  [name, team, position, height, weight, age] ->
    %{name: name, team: team, position: position,
      height: String.to_integer(height),
      weight: String.to_integer(weight),
      age: Float.parse(age) |> elem(0)
    }
end)
|> Enum.to_list() # THIS
```

Note the last line in the chain. Streams are to be **terminated** to retrieve the result. Until the termination happens, it’s lazily constructed, but not evaluated at all. That makes it possible to e.g. produce and operate infinite streams.

Any greedy function from `Enum` module would do: `Enum.take/2`, or, as I pointed out above, `Enum.to_list/1`.

---

For the sake of reference, in the future, when you feel fully familiar with [elixir](/questions/tagged/elixir), you might use [`Flow`](https://hexdocs.pm/flow) instead of `Stream` to parallelize mapping. For now (and for relatively small files) `Stream` is good enough.

Comment: The latter CSV uses _semicolons_ as delimiters; for it, you are to produce your own parser because the standard one expects _commas_.

Comment: I react just above to your advice

Comment: Instead of your last mapping, do what you want: `Stream.map(fn [_name, description, _enr_competences] -> description end)`.

Comment: Ah I will try that

Comment: You got back the list of maps. `Enum.map(list, & &1.description)` would map the content to descriptions and so forth.

Comment: It works, thanks! I will come back with many other Elixir subjects